# PHP include in head used for JS reference

Tags: javascript, php

This is a slightly weird question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere and I'm far from a pro at PHP.

Basically, two things, firstly, can you use the PHP include function in the head of a webpage?

Also, if that is possible, is it also possible to use the included PHP file for referencing Javascript files? Because I've finished my template and I've been looking at different ways I can make quick changes to all pages once completed, and of course, PHP include seemed best, however, I may want to reference a JS file sometime, so would it be possible to have in the `<head>` something like this:

```
 <?php include "ref.php"; ?>
```

And then that PHP file to look something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And then, that should reference jQuery into all pages that have ref.php included in the head. Or am I just being silly?

If there's any other ways I could reference a JS file on all pages, please let me now :)

Comment: Sure, why not? PHP is executed server side, HTML client side. So you can put PHP anywhere in the document where you want. you could even do something like echo("<html>").

Comment: I guess I'm just going to have to try some things out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's fine.  I think a term for the concept you're trying to go for could reasonably be "modularization".  You can separate your site into different modules so that you only have to update the code in your include rather than changing the code for say, 10 different pages every time.

PHP simply processes all your code before it gets sent to the client, so the client (i.e. any web browser) will simply see the output.

Theoretically, you could even do something like this (even though there wouldn't be much use for it).  This is simply to illustrate a point:

HTML:

```
<?php include "doctype.php"; ?>
    <html>
        <!-- etc. -->
```

doctype.php:

```
<!doctype html>
```

All the client would see is:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <!-- etc. -->
```

In my current site, I have the `head` in its own php file, my `header` (which contains navigation, etc.) in another php file, my `footer` in a php file, and then all my `script` elements inside yet another php file which is included at the end of the `body`.

Comment: Ah, nice, thanks for the info. I've only recently started using PHP include more and I can see it's damn useful!

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake i think in the syntax of include function , you may need to try this :

```
 <?php include("ref.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks yo, I have got PHP include functions on my page that look like the one in my question and they all work though

Answer (score 0):

By 'head of a web page' if you mean when beginning the code for a webpage, yes certainly you can do it. Infact it is more convenient to have repeating code blocks for all pages like the headers and footers stored as separate php files and then include them on pages. For eg `<?php <!DOCTYPE html> <html><head><title></title><script...></script>......</head><body>..........?>` in a file like head.php and `<?php </body><footer>.......</footer>` in a file like footer.php and them just use include on all pages

Comment: Well, currently I have made 3 templates (as there are three different styled type of pages) and when I make more pages, I'm going to copy each of my three templates to add content. I figured if the template (and therefore the finished pages) had a few different PHP includes in the head, I could use the included file to reference JS files for animation, if you understand what I mean :P

Comment: As I understand you have different templates for header(like to top banner, menu bar etc) and may be even for footer or other areas. You can certainly have those in different php files and then reference the required file on any page by using include ("file.php"). You can also use a conditional loop like the if() or switch to include different variants of the file depending upon certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this but I would recommend that you take the time to break up the ref.php into header.php and footer.php so that head would be above the fold (body tag) and the footer will have the closed BODY and HTML tag so you can add any remaining items you need to in the footer.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's a good point, thanks. My main focus here is if I want to add some Jquery effects (like falling snow) to all webpages, I figured I could just have a file which is just a Jquery/JS reference so the webpage can load it before the body, so hopefully this'll all work